# Upload de fotos para Storage da Amazon?

Tags: javascript, upload, amazon-aws, meteor

Quero colocar um formulário com um campo de upload de imagem no cliente  que faça o upload das fotos diretamente  para storage da Amazon S3,  sem que passe pelo servidor, usando Meteor, alguém pode apontar uma direção, alguma dica ?

Answer (score 0):

Esta pagina da documentação "[Authenticating Requests in Browser-Based Uploads Using POST (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html)" mostra como fazer issso.